# How to pick up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in IntelliJ Gradle build?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

When I run my gradle build using a run configuration, the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS that I have set in my ~/.zshenv gets picked up. The result is a successful build. However, when I import the project, reload the project in the gradle tab, or change the build.gradle externally (thus causing it to be reloaded by gradle), the build fails. The failure is due to a failure to resolve plugins. I use JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to set "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/my/cert/location", to set the locations of some certs that are needed for these dependencies.

This is very annoying because one of the core features of IntelliJ gradle integration is auto-building the project.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Gradle means](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) to set the JVM options for the Gradle daemon. For example with the Gradle [System Properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties):

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/my/cert/location
```